# Boldface timestamp tics with gnuplot for windows

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to have *timestamp* xtics displayed in boldface. I've tried this:

```
  set xdata time
  set format x "%d %b"     # output format
  set timefmt "%Y %b %d"      # input format
  set xtics format sprintf("{/:Bold %s}")
```

which displays bold timestamp xtics in seconds since 1 Jan 1970 as expected. Now, if I use the following format instead

```
set xtics format strftime("{/:Bold %d %b}",sprintf("{/: %s}"))
```

I obtain the desired output format (%d %b) but all of my tics become 01 jan (while in the previous case, that is, in seconds format, all tics were correct (and different one another)). Anyone see where I'm wrong ? I've also tried removing the %d %b format in the `set xtics format` statement, since it's already given in the `set format x` statement above (in case redundancy was causing the problem), but then I get no tics at all.

Answer (score 1):

What's going wrong is that the strftime function is being evaluated at the time you give the "set xtics" command rather than during the plotting.

I think you want

```
set xtics format "%d %b" font ":Bold"
```

Here is the output from one of the gnuplot demos modified to use exactly that:

[image]

Comment: I've tried that but it does not work, neither with set term win nor with set term jpeg. Anyway, you have given me a very good idea that has put me on the right track: the command would be set xtics format "{/:Bold %d %b}"